# array: set width for certain columns

Tags: arrays, width

I have an `array` (in math mode) for which I want the first column a little bit wider than the rest, and the rest should be of a consistent width. If I just write

```
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
10000 & 1 & 20 & 300
\end{array}
```

then the second, third and fourth column all have a separate width, which I want to avoid. Ideally I'd like to set the width of the first column to e.g. `2cm` and the width of the remaining ones to `1cm`.

Is there a way to do that? I'd like to avoid nested `array` environments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that (a) columns 2, 3, and 4 should all be as wide as the widest element in any one of the columns -- "300" in the table you've provided -- and (b) that the contents of these contents should be centered. If this interpretation is correct, I suggest you proceed by defining a new column type, called `C` in the code below, that satisfies these assumptions and also places its contents in math mode by default.

I've added vertical bars to the code to make it readily visible that columns 2, 3, and 4 are indeed equally wide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\mylen
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hfil$}p{\mylen}<{$\hfil}} % centered, in math mode, fixed width
\begin{document}
\[
\settowidth\mylen{300} % choose widest element in columns 2--4
\begin{array}{|c|C|C|C|}
10000 &  1  &  20 & 300\\
1     & 101 & 555 & 888\\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

**Update, June 2021**: In the 4+ years that have passed since I posted this answer, the `array` package has been updated significantly. One of the updates is the introduction of the `w` column type, with which the setup above could be rewritten more succinctly as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\mylen
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\begin{document}
\[
\settowidth\mylen{300} % choose widest element in columns 2--4
\begin{array}{| c | *{3}{wc{\mylen}|} }
10000 &  1  &  20 & 300\\
1     & 101 & 555 & 888
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't completely understand the `>{}p{}<{}` command, what do we need the `$` for? (Is there a reference for that command?)

Comment: @flawr - The `>{\hfil$} directive tells LaTeX to insert `\hfil$`  at the *start* of each cell, and the `<{$\hfil}` directive tells LaTeX to insert `$\hfill` at the *end* of each cell. The `$` particles initiate and terminate inline math mode automatically. (Since an `array` environment must occur in math mode and the `c` column type applies math mode automatically (if used in an `array`), I assumed that the `C` column type should place the associated cell contents in math mode as well.) The pair of `\hfil` directives serves to center the material inside the cell.

Comment: So if you use `p{}` it would define a text-mode column, and you need the `>{$}<{$}` for the mathmode *inside* that?

Comment: @flawr - That's correct: By itself, `p{<width parameter>}` would tell LaTeX to use text mode and to fully-justify the cell contents; think of  `p` as being short for "paragraph mode". The `>{...}` and `<{...}` directives serve to modify the default behavior.

Comment: Ok now I understand, thank you very much for answering my follow up questions!

Comment: @flawr - You're most welcome!

Comment: And for a right-aligned (math) column: `\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft$}p{\mylen}<{$}}` (why not use `\centering` instead of two `\hfil`s for centering text, by the way?)

Comment: @Maëlan - Thanks. If I were to modify/improve (?) this answer, it would be to employ the `w` column type, which wasn't available back when I first posted this answer, instead of the `p` column type. I've gone ahead and posted an addendum to show how the same output might be produced with the `w` column type.

Answer (score 4):

A possibility is with `dcolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r *{3}{D{.}{.}{3.-1}}}
\toprule
10000 &  1 & 20 & 300 \\
100   & 10 & 10 &  10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{r *{3}{D{.}{.}{3.-1}}}
\toprule
10000 & 100 & 200 & 300 \\
100   & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The second table shows the spacing is the same. The arguments to the `D` column type are, respectively the input decimal separator, the output decimal separator and the format of the numbers; here `3.-1` means “three digits in the integral part and no decimal digit.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `\hphantom` to get equal column width for the second to forth column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c|ccc}
    10000 & \hphantom{00}1 & \hphantom{0}20 & 300
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Column type `p` also works in `array`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{>{\centering}p{2cm}|*{3}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}}
    10000 & 1 & 20 & 300
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or aligned columns with package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{S[table-format=5]|*{3}{S[table-format=3]}}
    10000 & 1 & 20 & 300
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]