# How do I format the following table?

Tags: tables

Here is a MWE:

```
{
\textbf{EXACT VALUES OF TRIGONOMETRICAL RATIOS}\\\\
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Angle ($\theta$)} & &  &  \\ 
    Degrees & Radians & $\sin{\theta}$ & $\cos{\theta}$ & $\tan{\theta}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    $0^{\circ}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
    \hline 
    $30^{\circ}$ & $\frac{\pi}{6}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    $45^{\circ}$ & $\frac{\pi}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ & 1 \\ 
    \hline 
    $60^{\circ}$ & $\frac{\pi}{3}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\sqrt{3}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    $90^{\circ}$ & $\frac{\pi}{2}$ & 1 & 0 & undefined \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
}
```

Actual Table:[image]

Comment: Consider using `array`.

Comment: The table you posted is already complete.  What is the question?

Comment: Off-topic: Writing `\sin{\theta}`, `\cos{\theta}`, and `\tan{\theta}` is somewhat misleading, as the macros `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\tan` do not take arguments. It's better, and certainly cleaner, to write `\sin\theta`, `\cos\theta`, and `\tan\theta`.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. E.g., do you need an unusual math or text font? Do you need to render the contents of some cells in bold? Do you want the fractions typeset in display style? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing what improvement are you looking for, but this may be a start. I use `table` environment to have a caption, `array` environment so that I don't have to type `$` so much, fixed column width, `booktabs` commands and `\multirow` for multi-row text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hfil$}p{1.5cm}<{$\hfil}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340000/156344
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Exact values of trigonometrical ratios}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    $\begin{array}{CCCCC}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Angle ($\theta$)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\sin\theta$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\cos\theta$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\tan\theta$} \\ 
    \text{Degrees} & \text{Radians} & & & \\ 
    \midrule
    0^{\circ} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
    30^{\circ} & \frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
    45^{\circ} & \frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 \\ 
    60^{\circ} & \frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \sqrt{3} \\ 
    90^{\circ} & \frac{\pi}{2} & 1 & 0 & \text{undefined} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some colour and a different layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm, cmbright, calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}                          % Move cell content down
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{4ex}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{blue!15}}m{10ex}}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\rule{0pt}{4ex+1\tabcolsep}}m{0pt}@{}}   % To ensure equal row height 

 % Shortcuts
\newcommand*{\gray}{\cellcolor{gray!25}}
\newcommand*{\black}{\cellcolor{black}}
\newcommand*{\green}{\cellcolor{green!15}}

\arrayrulecolor{gray!15}                        % Light gray table rules

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|F|*{5}{C|}L}                                                    
                    \firsthline%
                    \gray{}Degrees        % Gray cell over blue column, \rowcolor not possible to use
                    &   \green\kern0.4em0^{\circ}
                    &   \green30^{\circ}
                    &   \green45^{\circ}
                    &   \green60^{\circ}
                    &   \green90^{\circ}
                    &   \\
                    \hline%
                    \gray{}Radians
                    &   \green 0
                    &   \green\frac{\pi}{6}
                    &   \green\frac{\pi}{4}
                    &   \green\frac{\pi}{3}
                    &   \green\frac{\pi}{2}
                    &\\
                    \hline%
                    sin($\bm{\theta}$)
                    &   0
                    &   \frac{1}{2}
                    &   \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
                    &   \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}
                    &   1
                    &\\
                    \hline%
                    cos($\bm{\theta}$)
                    &   1
                    &   \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}
                    &   \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
                    &   \frac{1}{2}
                    &   0
                    &\\
                    \hline%
                    tan($\bm{\theta}$)
                    &   0
                    &   \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}
                    &   1
                    &   \sqrt 3
                    &   \black
                    &   \\
                    \hline%
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]