# Nested Array Multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, arrays, nesting

```
\begin{array}{ll}
     1. (p \to q) \land (p \to r) & \text{premise} \\
     2. p \to q & \land \text{-elim(1)} \\
     3. p \to r & \land \text{-elim(1)} \\
     \multicolumn{2}{l}{
     \begin{array}{|ll|}
     \hline
        4. p  &  \text{assumption}\\
        5.  & 
     \end{array} 
     } \\

\end{array}
```

[image: Output]

Hi, so I just have a quick question. I'm trying to make a 2nd array inside the first one (i.e a nested array) but one annoying problem that I'm having is that the nested array doesn't seem to be able to take up more than one column. I'd prefer that the 2nd column on the inside of the nested array be close to the 2nd column of the outside array, but for some reason multicolumn doesn't extend the array beyond one column at all.

Comment: your nested array is spanning twocolumns, it is just not wide enough to show. Please always post examples as complete documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well then how would i make it so the 2nd column of the inner array is farther to the right?

Comment: any number of ways:  change`|ll|` to `|l@{\hspace{2in}}l|`or change `\multicolumn{2}{l}` to `\multicolumn{2}{r}`or ... But why have nested array you could not nest, and put assumption in the second column of the outer array

Comment: To set the width for a column, please see: [array: set width for certain columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339998/6865). Also: 
[TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and please include a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to explicitly use `array`, but to hide it in a new environment. Each line of the formal proof is input with either `\fps` or `\bfps` (the latter when lines in the margins are wanted).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{formalproof}
\newenvironment{formalproof}
 {%
  \begin{flushleft}%
  \setcounter{formalproof}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{|r @{ } l l|}%
 }
 {\end{tabular}\end{flushleft}}
\newcommand{\fps}[2]{% formal proof step
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\stepcounter{formalproof}\theformalproof.} &
  $#1$ &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\bfps}[2]{% boxed formal proof step
  \stepcounter{formalproof}\theformalproof. &
  $#1$ &
  #2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{formalproof}
\fps{(p \to q) \land (p \to r)}{premise} \\
\fps{p \to q}{$\land$-elim (1)} \\
\fps{p \to r}{$\land$-elim (1)} \\
\hline
\bfps{p}{assumption}\\
\bfps{?}{?}
\end{formalproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

By use of `tabularray` package you not need to nest `tabular` in `tabular`. Just add/define lines in table preamble where you like to have:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141591]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r Q[l, mode=math] l},
             cell{1-Z}{1} = {cmd=\arabic{rownum}. },  % for automatic numbering of rows
             hline{4}, vline{1,Z} = {4-Z}{},  % added lines in table
             }   
    &   (p \to q) \land (p \to r)   &   premise             \\
    &   p \to q                     & $\land$ -elim(1)      \\
    &   p \to r                     & $\land$ -elim(1)      \\
%
    &   p                           &   assumption          \\
    &                               &
\end{tblr}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution based on `eqparbox`, with some improvements:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{eqparbox}
    \newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle#2}}}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \begin{array}{lll}
         1. & \eqmathbox[M]{(p \to q) \land (p \to r) }& \text{premise} \\
         2. & p \to q & \land \text{-elim(1)} \\
         3. & p \to r & \land \text{-elim(1)} \\[0.5ex]
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{
        \hspace{-1ex} \begin{array}{|lll|}
         \hline
            4. & \eqmathbox[M]{p} & \text{assumption}\\
            5. & &
         \end{array}
         } \\
    \end{array}
     \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]